# What am I doing wrong with this MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql

I am simply trying to query some data, and I am using multiple WHERE options for the first time, and I do not know where I am going wrong:

```
SELECT *
FROM carlist
WHERE MilesPerGallon > 20
AND Weight is BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000;
```

MySQL Workbench keeps giving me an X near my first line:
[X Near First Line in MySQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVvpN.png)

And the system reports ErrorCode 1064: Error with Syntax.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Isn't it just `Weight BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000` (without the word IS)?

Comment: Note that you will want an index on (milespergallon,weight) - or vice versa

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM carlist
WHERE MilesPerGallon > 20
AND Weight BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000; -- removed is
```

Just saw the comment by @GrumpyCrouton! Posted simultaneously. Drop `is` before [`BETWEEN..AND..`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

Comment: @alkhalifas Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)